# Meteor accounts-password && accounts-google user creation conflict

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am working on a Meteor project. I have used accounts-password to create users and now I am trying to integrate with accounts-google plugin to provide OAuth support. Now the problem is if I use google oAuth login, and if I have already created an account with accounts-password with the same user email, its creating a duplicate account with new id. Is there a way to resolve this user accounts conflict ?

Comment: I am not sure how but you should be able to just add the Google service to the users services so just login with Google but don't create a new account and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use [link-accounts](https://atmospherejs.com/bozhao/link-accounts) package. This one will allow you to link any additional services to one user without creating new users.